# Visual Studio 2010 shortcut to go back from definition

Tags: visual-studio

**In Visual Studio when going to definition by pressing F12, it takes you to definition. Is there any way to go back to where you came from?**

This is specially annoying when you have definition within same file. If it's in another file then it's ok Ctrl+Tab take you back to previous window. But when it's in same file then have to find where you came from and go there.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Try the key combination: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd>.

Comment: Note that (At least on my german-swiss keyboard), you actually have to use the '-' key right from the dot key. You can't use the numpad.

Comment: If you want to jump forward you can use `Ctrl Shift -`

Comment: For those using newer versions of Visual Studio Code: the shortcut is `Alt` + `←`. Alternatively, click `Go` --> `Back`.

Answer (score 14):

As others mention, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd>. This is the `View-NavigateBackward` shortcut in Visual Studio's default key mapping scheme, and can be mapped to any key combination you like from Tools->Options->Keyboard.  I like <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> myself, to match typical web browser use.

Note that, for most five-button mice, the navigate-left button will also do this.

Comment: whats the difference between `View.NavigateBackward` (Ctrl - by default) and `View.Backward` (Alt Left by default) ?

Comment: I believe the latter works only in the web and object browser views.

Answer (score 6):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  +  <kbd>-</kbd>

Answer (score 5):

Ctrl -> '+' -> '-'
I searched for a long time till i found that one, and I can't stop using it since!! :)

Comment: This is incorrect. Pressing `Ctrl +`, followed by `Ctrl -`, is not the correct action. The "+" in the middle that you've included may come from confusion around what `Ctrl + -` means, outside of a context where one can see that the `Ctrl` and the `-` are the keys and the `+` indicates they are to be pressed together--not that the `+` key should be pressed.